# centering an article on wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I am working a portfolio, using a wordpress theme, you can see the website here:
***update: I have removed the link to the website because it is now changed***

I have tried every thread I could find but couldn't make it work.
The problem is that the portfolio blocks are not centered.

The only way I could center the text was by giving `.page #content article{padding-left:5%}`
However, I am sure there is a more elegant way of fixing this issue.

How can this be fixed?

Thanks in advance,
Yoni

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Usually, the simple way to center stuff in CSS is to use `margin: 0 auto;`. You may have to change other stuff in order for that to work though, for example if you set a width manually.

Comment: Hi Jose, Thanks for your quick reply! I have tried this method, but was not successful. Maybe I didnt apply it to the right elements... Can you be more specific with what element you think I should apply a width and what element to apply the margin: 0 auto; ?

Comment: create a div after this huge_it_portfolio_container_1

Answer (score 0):

**updated**

Add this style and try.

```
#huge_it_portfolio_content_1 #huge_it_portfolio_container_1 {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 88% !important;
    opacity: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: @Yoni, Answer updated. seems you didnt apply margin auto.

Comment: it works! Thanks a lot! I had to take the width from 88% to 90% because with 88% it showed as 2 columns, not 3.